# How to enable eAccelerator Caching/optimizer?

Tags: php

I just installed eAccelerator on a dedicated server.
The installation went fine, yet phpinfo() shows this:

```
eAccelerator support    enabled
Version 0.9.6.1
Caching Enabled false
Optimizer Enabled   false
Check mtime Enabled false
```

Can you explain me how i should enable the caching and optimizer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled it in `php.ini` or `/etc/php.d/eaccelerator.ini` file:

```
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
```

Don't forget to restart Apache to make it take effect.